# Django using loaddata from subfolder setup

Tags: python, django

Here's the INSTALLED_APPS setup

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    ...

    #imported old dependencies
    'lamusoftware.blog',
]
```

trying to loaddata to blog like so

```
(kpsga) sam@sam:~/code/kpsga$ python manage.py loaddata blog < new_blog.json 
CommandError: No fixture named 'blog' found.
```

or

```
(kpsga) sam@sam:~/code/kpsga$ python manage.py loaddata lamusoftware.blog < new_blog.json 
CommandError: Problem installing fixture 'lamusoftware': blog is not a known serialization format.
```

without restructuring the folder setup is there a way to make it work?